# illustrator - got RAM not enough error message and artwork now doesn't look right

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I got the error message re: Ram space while I was using Illustrator.  Now the artwork I was working on doesn't look it's supposed to look.... I closed all the other applications I was using, restarted my computer, opened the AI file again, but it's STILL looking weird!!!

I need to be able to view the original file... how to fix this program? Urgent, help greatly appreciated

Comment: This sounds like it'll likely be more of a tech-support question than a design one, but we still need more info either way.  What do you mean "looking weird?"

Comment: it doesn't show graphics correctly. doesn't show color (all black and white), and shapes turned into outlines...... need to present this to a client asap, what to do :/

Comment: Welcome user2277916! Thanks for posting your question, unfortunately technical support issues are [off-topic here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (you're more likely to get help asking on Adobe forums for hardware issues i.e. RAM error... although it sounds like Manly has your issue figured out).

Answer (score 1):

Based on your last comment, it sounds to me like you're in Outline Mode.  Your computer may have automatically swapped to this mode, because it's less taxing on your processor. The file itself is not altered, only the way your computer displays it on-screen.

Swap between Outline and Preview modes by clicking <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd>